# Using the Xbox 360 Controller in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, xbox360

I'm currently trying to use my Xbox 360 controller in my WPF application but all the tutorials online refer to using XNA in a game environment.  I was just wondering if there is an easy to get my application to detect my Xbox 360 controller and any movement/button pushes that may come from it.  My current setup is visual studio 2010, .NET 4.0, WPf, C#, and I have the xbox 360 wireless adapter for the PC.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider [Bruno Silva's solution for integrating the Xbox 360 gamepad with PowerPoint][x]. The first project was for an Office Add-in for Powerpoint, but the base project is a wrapper to allow the gamepad to be used within a Windows or WPF application.

> It wraps XNA `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.GamePad` class and provides an interface with events associated with each button status change, as well as on game pad connect/disconnect.

[Bruno Silva's blog has links to the project and sample code][x].

You'll need to have XNA Framework 2.0 installed. I'm unsure if higher/recent versions are compatible.

Comment: Is there an update on this answer? Have any newer add-ons for VisualStudio emerged or is this still the only way of getting this done? Also, what's the website mentioned in the answer?